# Explain FFT indexing with respect to bit reversal and digital reversal of fixed 5 indices

Tags: fft

Explain FFT indexing with respect to bit reversal and digital reversal of fixed indices

Comment: Show your efforts.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't show any effort whatsoever. It's simply a copy-paste.